# Colons are not being printed correctly

Tags: bash, shell, unix

NOTE: I do not know a lot about bash. Sorry if the answer is obvious.

I'm trying to make a script that prints text character by character from a file. While doing so I've notice that the colon (:) is replaced by `Illegal option -:
?` For some reason.
I do not know why this happens or how to stop it from happening, that's why I'm here.

Code (I got some of it from a stackoverflow question and added some of my own into it too):

```
#!/bin/sh
value=`cat $1`
iterate_over_chars()
{
    local seq="$1" OPTIND=1
    while getopts "$seq" opt "-$seq"; do
        echo -n "$opt"
        sleep 0.025
    done
}
iterate_over_chars "$value"
echo
echo
echo
echo END
```

To run it I enter

`sh name.sh test.txt`
test.txt:

```
test says: HI
```

The output is

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sh credits.sh test.txt
test saysIllegal option -:
? HI


END
```

Also changing echo -n "$opt" to echo -ne "$opt" prints -ne infront of the character instead of using the arguments n and e. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: `getopts` is not a good way to iterate over characters. Several characters (including ":") have special meanings to it, and can make this construction fail.

Comment: alright i fixed the script using a better alternative. Thanks

Comment: And for why `echo -anything` is unpredictable, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid `getopts` too. Bash has various kinds **Parameter Expansion** that are a more native way of manipulating strings. In this case, `${s:0:1}` can be used to snag the first character of the string `s`, with `${s#?}` used to emit all but the first character of that string.

Here's one way of using those forms. I'm also reading the file one line at a time via the `read` builtin in a while loop instead of capturing the output of `cat` using backticks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[ $# -eq 1 ] || { echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <file>" 1>&2; exit 1; }
[ -r "$1" ] || { echo "$1: cannot read" 1>&2; exit 1; }

iterate_over_chars() {
  local s="$1"
  while [ "$s" != '' ]; do
    echo -n "${s:0:1}"
    s=${s#?}
    sleep 0.025
  done
  echo
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
  iterate_over_chars "$line"
done < "$1"
```